# Get list of database depends on chosen server

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-2008

I'm using C# with framework 4.0 and SQL server 2008 R2.
I have listed the SQL server 2008 with this code:

```
 public static string[] GetSQLServerList()
        {
            SqlDataSourceEnumerator dse = SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance;
            DataTable dt = dse.GetDataSources();
            if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                return null;
            }

            string[] SQLServers = new string[dt.Rows.Count];
            int f = -1;
            foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
            {
                string SQLServer = r["ServerName"].ToString();
                string Instance = r["InstanceName"].ToString();
                if (Instance != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Instance))
                {
                    SQLServer += "\\" + Instance;
                }
                SQLServers[System.Math.Max(System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(ref f), f - 1)] = SQLServer;
            }
            Array.Sort(SQLServers);
            return SQLServers;
        }
```

i listed my Server on ComboBox.

How can I list the database, depends on which server that I choose in  ComboBox?

I found this [tutorial](http://4rapiddev.com/csharp/c-get-list-of-databases-in-sql-server/), but it needs `sqlconnection`, how can I connect when I have not chosen the server ?

Comment: what's the difference between `SQLServers[System.Math.Max(System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(ref f), f - 1)] = SQLServer;`

and 

`sqlServers[++f] = sqlServer;`

In this method?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is how you get a list of server names on the network:

```
List<String> ServerNames = new List<String>();

 SqlDataSourceEnumerator servers = SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance;
 DataTable serversTable = servers.GetDataSources();

     foreach (DataRow row in serversTable.Rows) {
            string serverName = row[0].ToString();

             try {

                if (row[1].ToString() != "") {

                            serverName += "\\" + row[1].ToString();

                }


              }
              catch {


              }

              ServerNames.Add(serverName);
      }
```

To Get a List of databases from selected server:

```
List<String> databases = new List<String>();

SqlConnectionStringBuilder connection = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

 connection.DataSource = SelectedServer;
 // enter credentials if you want
 //connection.UserID = //get username;
// connection.Password = //get password;
 connection.IntegratedSecurity = true;

 String strConn = connection.ToString();

 //create connection
  SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(strConn);

//open connection
sqlConn.Open();

 //get databases
DataTable tblDatabases = sqlConn.GetSchema("Databases");

//close connection
sqlConn.Close();

//add to list
foreach (DataRow row in tblDatabases.Rows) {
      String strDatabaseName = row["database_name"].ToString();

       databases.Add(strDatabaseName);


}
```

Comment: @user609511: you'll have to connect to each server to get its databases.

Comment: Connect to the instance, database `master`, and execute `sp_databases` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176070.aspx

Comment: @user609511 see how to build the connection string above

Answer (score 1):

```
    using (var connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("ConnectionString"))
    {
        connection.Open();
        var command = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.CommandText = "SELECT name FROM master.sys.databases";

        var adapter = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(command);
        var dataset = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(dataset);
        DataTable dtDatabases = dataset.Tables[0];
    }
```