# Get all databases in Azure server using C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sql-database, database-connection

I'm trying to get all databases names in the Azure server using C#, but I'm unable to find the connection string for it. I would like to get all the database names from the server once the user provides id and password.

Comment: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/master/articles/mysql/media/howto-connection-strings/connection-strings-on-portal.png Can you check this on your azure

Comment: Hey, I have seen that in connection string it asking me to give DB name in the string itself. here, I would like to get all the databases from the server once the user gives me id and password.

Comment: you can call some sql Like leon's answer. it will give you the list of db from the sql server

Comment: Connected to the instance, database master and then executed sys.databases query it gave me all the databases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please look at this tutorial: [View a List of Databases on an Instance of SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/view-a-list-of-databases-on-an-instance-of-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017).

This topic describes how to view a list of databases on an instance of SQL Server by using SQL Server Management Studio or Transact-SQL.

For example:

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;  
GO  
SELECT name, database_id, create_date  
FROM sys.databases ;  
GO
```

This also works for Azure SQL database.

First, you need to using the connection string to your Azure SQL. Then run the query in  you c# APP, it will return all the database in your Azure SQL Server.

Or, you can reference the answer of this blog: [Get list of database depends on chosen server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13686433/get-list-of-database-depends-on-chosen-server):

To Get a List of databases from selected server:

```
List<String> databases = new List<String>();

SqlConnectionStringBuilder connection = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

 connection.DataSource = SelectedServer;
 // enter credentials if you want
 //connection.UserID = //get username;
// connection.Password = //get password;
 connection.IntegratedSecurity = true;

 String strConn = connection.ToString();

 //create connection
  SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(strConn);

//open connection
sqlConn.Open();

 //get databases
DataTable tblDatabases = sqlConn.GetSchema("Databases");

//close connection
sqlConn.Close();

//add to list
foreach (DataRow row in tblDatabases.Rows) {
      String strDatabaseName = row["database_name"].ToString();

       databases.Add(strDatabaseName);


}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thankyou Connected to the instance, database master and then executed sys.databases query it gave me all the databases.